# rewrite multiple domains .TLD by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, url-rewriting

we think about rewrite for huge parked domains about ~600 domains;
our htaccess becomes lage and cause negative performance;
ok

*for example: rewrite for about 300 .net domains that we dont know whats those FQDN, domains my contain A-Z + - + 0-9 & minus between charachters;*

something like this:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^?\.com$ [OR,NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^?\.net$
    RewriteRule ....here is some rule....
```

Comment: ok i solved; مودونوم و نوموگوم هاا

Answer (score 0):

only should use wildcard as fqdn because we dont know what the 
        ^*.com [OR]